# italicizing the first letter but NOT the rest of the letters of a word in text() in R

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I can plot the word "***p*-value**" (*just as shown here*; i.e., letter "***p***" in *italics* and **boldfaced** but rest of the letters only **bold-faced**)?

I'm trying the **following R code** with no success:

```
plot(1:10, ty="n", ann=F)

text( 2.5, 9.5, bquote(bolditalic(p),bold(-value)), cex = 1.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pasting the 'p' and '-value' together within expression():

```
text( 2.5, 9.5, expression(paste(bolditalic("p"),bold("-value"))), cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: this solution also works with bquote instead of expression